# Access Sonarqube Webapi with python requests

Tags: python, sonarqube, python-requests

i quite new to `pyhton`. I just try a simple way to get an `HTTP` response with python to a simple get from the sonar Web API

i use the request library and try a simple use :

```
project = requests.get(url=Sonar_Api_Projects_Search, params=param_Projects, verify=False, headers={'Authorization': 'token {}'.format(token)})
```

the request is well formatted and work fine when i use it in e web browser.

but as a response i get this strange output :

> {"err_code":500,"err_msg":"undefined method `empty?' for
>   nil:NilClass\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/lib/authenticated_system.rb:132:in`
>   login_from_basic_auth'\n\torg/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in
>   `call'\n\torg/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in`
>   call'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/http_authentication.rb:126:in
>   `authenticate'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/http_authentication.rb:116:in`
>   authenticate_with_http_basic'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/lib/authenticated_system.rb:129:in
>   `login_from_basic_auth'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/lib/authenticated_system.rb:11:in`
>   current_user'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:102:in `set_user_session'\n\torg/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2223:in`
>   send'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in
>   `evaluate_method'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in`
>   call'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:225:in
>   `call'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:629:in`
>   run_before_filters'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:615:in
>   `call_filters'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in`
>   perform_action_with_filters'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in
>   `perform_action_with_benchmark'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in`
>   ms'\n\tjar:file:/D:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in
>   `realtime'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in`
>   ms'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in
>   `perform_action_with_benchmark'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in`
>   perform_action_with_rescue'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in `perform_action_with_flash'\n\torg/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2223:in`
>   send'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in
>   `process'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in`
>   process_with_filters'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in
>   `process'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in`
>   call'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:450:in
>   `call'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in`
>   dispatch'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:85:in
>   `dispatch'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in`
>   _call'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in
>   `build_middleware_stack'\n\torg/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in`
>   call'\n\torg/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in
>   `call'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in`
>   call'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in
>   `cache'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in`
>   cache'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in
>   `call'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in`
>   call'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:67:in
>   `call'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in`
>   call'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in`
>   call'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in
>   `call'\n\tfile:/D:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/session_store.rb:70:in`
>   context'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:58:in
>   `call'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in`
>   call'\n\tD:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in
>   `call'\n\tfile:/D:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:34:in`
>   serve_rails'\n\tfile:/D:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:39:in
>   `call'\n\tfile:/D:/sonarqube-5.6.6_20170214/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:22:in`
>   call'\n"}

Can someone help me ?

Thanks a lot

Best regards

Arnaud

Comment: You should first consider to upgrade to latest LTS, 6.7.

Comment: Unfortunattely i'm not in charge with the SonarQube installation. IS it a known issues with the 5.6.6 version ? By the way when i do the same code with .Net code it works.

Comment: The issue is coming from the authentication. Are you sure of "headers={'Authorization': 'token {}'.format(token)}" ?

Comment: Everything i try in this object produce the same result (if i suppress token, if i write Basic instead of token). Actually i'm not sure for anything. I just know if i suppress the authorization, i get a 401 response (that is logical).

Comment: I've no idea how the Python request library is working with basic authentication, you should have a look at the doc, see for instance this first result from google : http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication.

Comment: I suggest to try with curl to know the correct request expected. Then try to display the one sent by Request.

Answer (score 7):

Direct use of requests never worked for me.

I do the following and it is working fine:
(below code is to list projects in Sonar)

```
import json , requests, pprint

url = 'http://sonar_url:9000/api/projects/search'
myToken = 'fa2377941a95125443f4efade615512jjkd221211a48'

session = requests.Session()
session.auth = myToken, ''

call = getattr(session, 'get')
res = call(url)
print(res.status_code)

binary = res.content
output = json.loads(binary)
pprint.pprint(output)
...
#Parse json result
```

Comment: https://github.com/kako-nawao/python-sonarqube-api/blob/master/sonarqube_api/api.py#L66

Comment: note that not all SonarQube installs are listening on port 9000... I have used some that listen on 80 and 443; try those if requests are stalled.

Comment: Any idea why creating a session works but not a direct call on an http method on requests? I understand that a session provides cookie persistence, connection-pooling, and configuration, but what about these things does SonarQube's api see and allow vs direct use of requests?

Comment: Awesome. I was struggling with SonarQube developer Edition 9.2 . Nothing else was working. This worked right away!

Answer (score 3):

In Sonarqube 8.9, `requests` is working for me.

First, you should should create an API token.  Per the docs:

> This is the recommended way. Benefits are described in the page User Token. The token is sent via the login field of HTTP basic authentication, without any password.

The docs go on to provide a weird `curl` usage example:

```
# note that the colon after the token is required in curl to set an empty password 
curl -u THIS_IS_MY_TOKEN: https://sonarqube.com/api/user_tokens/search
```

In `requests`, this looks something like this:

```
response = requests.get(
    "http://your-sonar-instance.com/api/blah",
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth("Some Sonarqube API token", "")
)

return json.loads(response.text)
```

See https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/extend/web-api/ for API details.

Also note that `auth=HTTPBasicAuth("token", "")` seems to behave differently from `auth=HTTPBasicAuth("token", None)`.

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old question. Thankfully there is a wrapper library available now - https://github.com/shijl0925/python-sonarqube-api. It works quite well and is easy to setup.

If possible people from Sonarsource could make it the official one so that more people start using it and it gets maintained in the future too.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck as well on this today and I wanted to share a solution which is basically the same as Alex's but for my purposes works better with the wrappers we wrote around requests.

Replace base64_encode() with your favorite routine that base64 encodes a string:

```
headers = {"Authorization": "Basic {0}".format(base64_encode(myToken + ":"))}
```

I believe this is equivalent to:

```
auth=HTTPBasicAuth(myToken, "")
```

I've got a new problem as SonarQube says I didn't provide a project argument even though I did. But my auth issue was resolved with the above code.